# trying github python package - need to get the committer email in specific branch to send out notification

Tags: github, github-api, pygithub

Am using circle ci to integerate with github and using slack for notification.
My use case :

1. is to get the emailid's of contributors to the specific branch so that i can notify those dev's regarding pipeline failure.
2. is to get latest merged pr to master and contributors in that pr so tha i can notify those dev's regarding pipeline